# how to install confluent in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I wanted to use confluent in AWS EC2 environment. How can I install it. I have tried the confluent cli in my local and want to replicate this feature of connecting sql to kafka. Is there any documentation on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find how to install Confluent Platform from DEB or YUM sources in Confluent docs. Otherwise, extract the same package you would have done locally.

[There's AWS quickstart templates](https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/confluent-platform/) or Ansible setups on Confluent Github for setting up a full cluster. Or you could use EKS to run it in Kubernetes, if that's something you're comfortable with. I'm sure there's some third party Terraform repos out there as well...

For non-container, production use cases, you'd use systemctl to start services on independently running servers, not all Confluent services on just one system like with `confluent start`

Sounds like you just want to run KSQL, but it's not clear if/where you have a running Kafka cluster

Comment: So, I want to use the kafka connect feature, where if I a row is added to a table then a new message is published to a topic. Currently, I tested this in my local using confluent and it works well. However, I want to take this to prod env. How can I achieve this. As of now, I don't have a kafka cluster. What is the best/easiest way to go about this?

Comment: The easiest way would probably be Amazon MSK or Confluent Cloud if you don't want to manage Kafka (and Zookeeper) yourself

Comment: These are paid versions right? How do I use free versions. Managing a normal kafka cluser is fine but how do I incorporate the kafka connect feature. Are there  any links explaining this?

Comment: EC2 is still "paid"... I feel like there's plenty of documentation for installing Zookeeper and Kafka. Kafka Connect just requires one more machine and editing the appropriate configuration files for it (again, listed in the Kafka and Confluent documentation sites)

Comment: I updated my answer to include the AWS quickstart templates

Answer (score 0):

you just need to download confluent zip from here 
https://www.confluent.io/download/

unzip in your desired folder

for start confluent services

go to confluent bin   /path to extract folder/confluent/bin

for start all confluent service
  confluent start

for check service status

confluent status

for stop service
  confluent stop

Comment: It will definitely work on production to....u didn't get any notification on service failure that the only thing...

Comment: @user331 `confluent start` is not meant to be used for production, no. For example, all data stored by it is temporary

Comment: so then how do we configure it for production. Or rather what should be used for production.